# Highchart plugin does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am using a simple plugin from http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic which has a javascript file stored in view options. I am using this file in my `index.html` code as `<script src="js/pie1.js"></script>` inside `<body>` tag where pie1 is a javascript file stored in js folder. When i run my html page nothing happens.

can anyone help me where I am getting wrong? I am new to using plugins so please bear with me and correct me if anything is wrong.

Comment: > `<script src="js/pie1.js"></script>`

- there is no such tag on the page.

Comment: check browser console

Comment: Do you have live demo of that website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have this situation because javascript start running the plugin  before your html is ready.

Place `<script src="js/pie1.js"></script>` just before closing tag `</body>`

Comment: my code is correctly placed. i think it has more to do with highcharts code. because when edit that code in jsfiddle.net, it still does not work. it however shows the pie chart when i open in from the given edit jsfiddle link